# Does a typical USB memory stick have internal Battery (Capacitor)?

Tags: memory

I would be curious to know how the bits are kept intact without a power / voltage source.  In ancient times multivibrator circuits, flip-flops,  were used to retain memory in single bits but need power or they reset.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=non-volatile+memory

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/376498/what-is-the-secret-behind-the-non-volatile-effect-of-the-flash-memories?rq=1