# MicroSDHC cannot be formatted, deleted, only read

Tags: format, fat32, micro-sd-card

I have a MicroSDHC SanDisk Ultra (Red Grey) with 10 Speed Class, UHS-I Bus Interface, and 16GB Size Storage. I put this on the SanDisk Adapter to connect it on PC (Windows 10) and it is readable. But there is a popup message "There's a problem with this drive, scan the drive now and fix it",

[image]

and I go for "Scan and Fix (Recommended)"

[image]

then "Repair this Drive" but it said theres no error

[image]

I was trying to format it via CMD, PowerShell, a lot of Third Party Tools, and SD Card Formatter by sdcard.org official SDA Foundation. But the result is always same, that is this drive cannot be formatted, or failed.

The SDHC can be read, also some files can be copied to my PC Drive, and some aren't. If I delete the folder or files inside of it, it will get deleted, but it will appear again after I re-plug the SDHC card.

[image]

Is there any way to Format this microSDHC card?

Comment: This is a common failure mode of USB and SD cards.  Replace it.

Comment: what d u mean by replace it?

Comment: @Gxogac It is physically broken, get your data off the card and buy a new one.

Comment: @mashuptwice I'm wondering, if its broken, why some files still can be copied?

Comment: If your cars tires are flat, doesn't mean it can't drive anymore. While the tires of a car are fixable, a flash memory is not.

Comment: @mashuptwice yeah, but its not the entire files cant be copied, but some. maybe 90%

Comment: so what cause this error?

Comment: **a physically broken flash media** causes behavior like this. Your question got flagged as duplicate. You can find a detailed explanation in the [original question](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)

Comment: I never pull out the card until this happen, how can it physically broken?

Comment: Flash memory dies over time as it is written. Writing to is is a destructive process that depending on the media means that particular areas of the drive may only  enable to be written 1,000 or 10,000 or more times. After a while areas of the memory become unwriteable and you taking it out is irrelevant to that. Copy off what you can and replace it.

Comment: @Mokubai oh you meant a SD Card write cycle limit? how can I get the specific value for that? I cant find on the internet

Comment: @Gxogac you can't.  It's hidden behind whatever proprietary controller the sd card uses. You know you've hit a write limit on critical blocks when the card either becomes corrupt, read only, or simply stops working altogether.

Comment: Note that this isn't necessarily a set value, but a approximation of the physical limit how often a flash can be written.

Comment: @Mokubai If I format an SD Card, does it reset the write cycle or not?

Comment: @Gxogac there is no way to reset the write cycles, it  is a physical property of the flash memory. Every time a flash cell is erased ready to be rewritten will cause damage and it is impossible to reverse. Formatting cannot help because that is simply another way of writing to the device. Throw it out and buy a new card. See https://superuser.com/a/376525/19943 for some info on flash at the physical level